# Learning HTML and Bootstrap by recreating my website, and I had some general questions

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, blogs, portfolio

I'm trying to teach myself more about web design and development by recreating my [WordPress portfolio Site](http://skistadstudios.com), and I eventually want to completely replace my site with this new one. I've done my research and taken a few classes on it, but I had a few general questions:

How would I make the blog section? Would I still want to use something like a WordPress database, or would I be creating all of that from scratch? Are there other tools you'd recommend?

What would you recommend for storing data for the portfolio grid? On my current website each entry is a post type, though that's through WordPress.

I've noticed a lot of WordPress themes have very similar functionality, and many of them use Bootstrap. Is there something the equivalent to a library that these themes use for things like landing pages, post grids, ect?

If you even just had a few links to throw at me to point me in the right direction, that'd be great. I've searched around, but haven't found too much.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm attempting to recreate my WordPress website in HTML using Bootstrap.

Comment: You are trying to recreate a website without using wordpress, is that correct?

Comment: This is far too broad for SO and contains requests for off site resource recommendations, which are explicitly off topic. Please review [ask].

Comment: For the most part, yes. If WordPress is still the best option for the blog section specifically, I'm not opposed to it. I'm not quite sure how I'd integrate it into a custom made site though.

Answer (score 0):

**How would i make the blog section?**

If you are using wordpress, well, you don't have to, wordpress have a Post section specified for blogs.

**Would I still want to use something like a WordPress database, or would I be creating all of that from scratch?**

Yes, if you are using wordpress, they have their own database, it's not suggested to modify it at all. But if you are not using wordpress, you have to design your database from scratch and either use a database system like MySQL or MSSQL etc.

**What would you recommend for storing data for the portfolio grid? On my current website each entry is a post type, though that's through WordPress.**

Again, if you are using wordpress, there's probably a plugin you can install to show your portfolio, the database table is automatically created when you install the plugin.

**I've noticed a lot of WordPress themes have very similar functionality, and many of them use Bootstrap. Is there something the equivalent to a library that these themes use for things like landing pages, post grids, ect?**

Well, Bootstrap is a popular frontend framework, that's why alot of sites use it. No there's no equivalent libarary these themes use, the equivalent libarary is Bootstrap, and then you customize your landing pages, post grids, etc with your own css/script.

**If you even just had a few links to throw at me to point me in the right direction, that'd be great. I've searched around, but haven't found too much.**

Look up different themes and templates here if you need it, there's wordpress specific themes too [Themeforest](https://themeforest.net/)

Comment: Oh my, my apologies! I never mentioned in my post that I'm recreating it in HTML using Bootstrap, not using WordPress.

Comment: Well, that's going to be a long story then. Database design, Frontend design, Application Logic, Image modify/storage etc...If you are just a beginner, Look at this [How to create a simple blog using mvc](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1), This blog post is abit outdated, but you will have some general idea on what you'll need to do, the framework used is ASP.NET MVC.